# Commit files together in svn repository from a sparse checkout

Tags: svn

I am trying to commit files in SVN with sparse checkout. With sparse here I mean I first checked out empty repository and then updated certain directories only.

So in my use case directory structure is.

```
+svn_project/
|
---+etc
|  |
|  ---+cfg
|     |
|     ---+config1
|
---+src
|  |
|  ---+java
|     |
|     ---+Test.java
|
---+lib
---+test
```

I did a empty checkout of svn_project using:

```
svn co -q --depth=empty file:///var/tmp/projects/svn_project/trunk/ /var/tmp/projects/temp
```

Then I checked out cfg and java directories using:

```
svn co -q --depth=empty file:///var/tmp/projects/svn_project/trunk/etc/cfg /var/tmp/projects/temp/etc/cfg
svn update /var/tmp/projects/temp/etc/cfg/config1
svn co -q --depth=empty file:///var/tmp/projects/svn_project/trunk/src/java /var/tmp/projects/temp/src/java
svn update /var/tmp/projects/temp/src/java/Test.java
```

I tried committing config1 and Test.java with CWD from /var/tmp/projects/temp but it is failing. Is it possible to commit these files together when we are doing sparse checkouts.

I know with cvs we can specify repository root and commit files from anywhere.

Comment: why not provide error message for better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with Subversion. With Subversion, commits are atomic and may only be be performed from a single working copy.

In your case, `/var/tmp/projects/temp/etc/cfg` and `/var/tmp/projects/temp/src/java` are independent working copies with a common directory which is **not** managed by Subversion, so you cannot commit them with a single `svn commit`.

Comment: Is it possible to checkout files on demand and still have single copy. That is not to checkout whole repository, but at end have setup similar to what is descried in question.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use sparse checkouts and only have a handful of files. But what you've done here has not created a single working copy - you've created two independent working copies.

Comment: How to create single working copy and do sparse checkout like the way I shown?